# Does iOS upgrade retain NSUserDefaults?

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

As far as I know, yes: upgrading iOS should not delete NSUserDefaults. Only deleting the app should do so.

But I am looking into a bug that can only be explained - so far - by iOS resetting NSUserDefaults after upgrade. Can this happen?

Comment: @rmaddy I don't think there's any duplicate. He's asking about what happens when you upgrade the system, not what happens when you update an app.

Comment: How precisely was this upgrade performed, and what information was lost?

Comment: @matt I did misread the question. Sleiman - If an iOS upgrade removed NSUserDefaults, it would be big news for breaking every app a user has each time iOS was updated.

Comment: @rmaddy But that's why I asked how it was performed. I can think of a way to lose data by upgrading iOS. It would be a dumb thing to do, but people do dumb things...

Comment: Thanks for your comments! I don't exactly know the details of how the problem occurred as it happened to someone in the testing team. I haven't tested it myself yet. I hear you it would be outrageous news if iOS upgrade causes NSUserDefaults to be deleted. I will be looking deeper in the code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have never seen an OS upgrade erase an app's user defaults. They are stored in the app's sandbox directory, which is not touched by the upgrade.

Upgrading an app also does not erase user defaults. The only things I'm aware of that erase user defaults are deleting the app, and doing a restore on the device (which wipes EVERYTHING.)

Do you have access to the device in question? if so, you should connect it to a development Mac and capture the app's sandbox directory. You can then check to see what's there.

Comment: Thanks Duncan! I have not had access to the device in question but I will.